# How to set certain custom order on x variables in seaborn plots?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

For example I have am plotting box plots this way :-

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
sns.boxplot(x='class',y='age',data=titanic, palette='rainbow')
plt.title("Age by Passenger Class, Titanic")
```

[image]

I want to set the order of class like `Thrid class`,`First class` ,`Second Class` from left to right on the box plots then what should I do?

NOTE :
Tried `hue_order` but I find no difference in the results
[image]

Comment: `boxplot` has `hue_order` so that you can specify the order of the group. In your case though, you can probably just do `plt.invert_yaxis()`.

Comment: ok let me check out this parameter